# how to reduce unwanted space in table cell

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

In my html,i am using a table to display from and to date picker.After fixing the date picker,the  cell is taking lot of space so i am not able to keep that table to aside of my web page.

This is my html ,

```
<table border="1"  cellspacing="0" >
  <tr>
    <td><input id="ir-box" type="checkbox"/></td><td colspan="3">Only show LIVE reports</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" value="Keyword Search"/></td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Incident types" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="incident-type" type="text" value="All Location types"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">From</td><td colspan="2">To</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input class="datefield" id="fromdate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td><td colspan="2"><input class="datefield" id="todate" type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>s</td><td>f</td><td>s</td><td>{% include "buttons/go.html" %}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using django web framework,designing web page using html.

1.How to reduce the space inside the  cell so that i can keep the table aside of my webpage.Help required

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce space with the cellpadding in HTML like this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_cellpadding2

The right method is to set padding to the td with CSS

Answer (score 0):

You simply just apply the padding in your CSS file appropriately for the table. For example (CSS)

```
tr {padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}
```

This is top, right, bottom, left and a shorthand way of stating the padding.

More: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp